# Having issues with isEqual

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make it detect whether the elements within a 2D Array are all equal but I keep getting "true" for all of them regardless of whether it's Equal or not.

```
const isEqual = (currentValue) => currentValue = 5
const r = 0

array = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,5,5,5],
  [6,7,8,9],
  [10,11,12,13]
];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result = (array[i].every(isEqual));
      if(result == true) {
          r == i + 1
      }
   console.info("Row " + [i] + " has all equal values.")
}
```

And was expecting it to say Row 2 has all equal values.

But instead I got this

```
Row 0 has all equal values.
Row 1 has all equal values.
Row 2 has all equal values.
Row 3 has all equal values.
```

Comment: `currentValue = 5` assigns the `5` to `currentValue` and in this context returns it as `true`. It does not compare a value to `5`. Try `currentValue === 5`.

Comment: Also be aware of no matter what you change, your `console.log` is not inside the check.

Comment: Also, you're not checking if the row `has all equal values`, but if all values equal 5. For example, a row with `[6,6,6,6],` would not be detected as all equal.

Answer (score 0):

- Your isEqual function should use a comparison operator (===) instead of an assignment operator (=)
- You need to update the console.info() call to only execute when the result is true

```js
const isEqual = (currentValue) => currentValue === 5;
let r = 0;

array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 5, 5, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12, 13],
];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result = array[i].every(isEqual);
  if (result === true) {
    r = i + 1;
    console.info("Row " + [i] + " has all equal values.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks this helps a ton, originally I had console.info() inside the if statement but moved it out when I was trying something else. Thanks for the help!